# MySQL Join and create new column value

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have an instrument list and teachers instrument list.

I would like to get a full instrument list with id and name.

Then check the teachers_instrument table for their instruments and if a specific teacher has the instrument add `NULL` or `1` value in a new column.

I can then take this to loop over some instrument checkboxes in Codeigniter, it just seems to make more sense to pull the data as I need it from the DB but am struggling to write the query.

```
teaching_instrument_list

- id
- instrument_name

 teachers_instruments

- id
- teacher_id
- teacher_instrument_id

 SELECT
  a.instrument,
  a.id
 FROM
   teaching_instrument_list a
 LEFT JOIN
 (
    SELECT teachers_instruments.teacher_instrument_id
    FROM teachers_instruments
    WHERE teacher_id = 170
 ) b ON a.id = b.teacher_instrument_id
```

my query would look like this:

```
 instrument name    id   value
 ---------------    --   -----
 woodwinds          1    if the teacher has this instrument, set 1
 brass              2     0
 strings            3     1
```

Comment: What's the point of the surrogate key in `teachers_instruments`?

Comment: Sorry, but your question is a bit vague. Are you trying to count the number of teachers using each instrument in question? Then LEFT JOIN your `ti` table and use COUNT(teacher_id) to, well, do the counting.

Comment: I guess it's not needed.

Comment: I updated the thread, hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach:

```
    SELECT i.instrument_name, COUNT(ti.teacher_id) AS used_by 
      FROM teaching_instrument_list AS i
 LEFT JOIN teachers_instruments AS ti
        ON ti.teacher_instrument_id = i.id
  GROUP BY ti.teacher_instrument_id
  ORDER BY i.id;
```

Here's [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc4be/3) (tables' naming is a bit different).

Explanation: with `LEFT JOIN` on `instrument_id` we'll get as many `teacher_id` values for each instrument as teachers using it are - or just a single `NULL` value, if none uses it. The next step is to use `GROUP BY` and `COUNT()` to, well, group the result set by instruments and count their users (excluding NULL-valued rows).

If what you want is to show all the instruments and some flag showing whether or now a teacher uses it, you need another LEFT JOIN:

```
    SELECT i.instrument_name, NOT ISNULL(teacher_id) AS in_use
      FROM teaching_instrument_list AS i
 LEFT JOIN teachers_instruments AS ti
        ON ti.teacher_instrument_id = i.id
       AND ti.teacher_id = :teacher_id;
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc4be/9).

Comment: that's great! How can I add a where clause for only 1 user (WHERE ti.teacher_id = X)?

Answer (score 1):

Well this can be achieved like this

```
SELECT
  id,
  instrument_name,
  if(ti.teacher_instrument_id IS NULL,0,1) as `Value`
from teaching_instrument_list as til
  LEFT JOIN teachers_instruments as ti
    on ti.teacher_instrument_id = til.id
```

Add a column and check for teacher_instrument_id. If found set Value to 1 else 0.