# php list and select data using join tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have this database table structure for posts, categories and post_categories

posts:

```
| id | title | details
| 1  | test  | test details
```

categories:

```
| id |     name     | parent_id
|  1 |   cat one    |     0
|  2 |   cat two    |     0
|  3 |   cat three  |     0
```

post_categories

```
|  category_id  |  post_id
|      1        |     1
|      2        |     1
```

I insert multiple categories using input checkbox for each post in `post_categories` table. Now in update page(`domain.com/admin/posts/1/edit`) i need to show categories list and checked input checkbox.can i generate this output using join two table(`categories and post_categories`) Or I need to separate two query(first from `post_category` table and second from `categories` table) like this output?! (my choice is join method so how to generate use join method?)

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" checked> cat one
<input type="checkbox" value="2" checked> cat two
<input type="checkbox" value="3"> cat three  //unchecked (not in post_categories table)
```

**update:** 
for list categories query:

```
$query = $this->db->table('categories')
    ->select('id, name, parent_id')
    ->get()
    ->getResultObject();
```

data in print_r:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => cat one
            [parent_id] => 0
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => cat two
            [parent_id] => 0
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => cat three
            [parent_id] => 0
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => cat4
            [parent_id] => 2
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 5
            [name] => cat5
            [parent_id] => 0
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 6
            [name] => cat6
            [parent_id] => 0
        )

)
```

after join:

```
$query = $this->db->table('categories')
    ->select('id, name, parent_id')
    ->join('post_categories', 'post_categories.category_id = id','left outer')
    ->where('post_categories.post_id', $id)
    ->get()
    ->getResultObject();
```

and data is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => cat one
            [parent_id] => 0
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => cat two
            [parent_id] => 2
        )

)
```

result after join is false.

Comment: it's totally upon you. with one query is better

Comment: @ZaheerAhmad: my choice is one query using join method. can u tell me how to?

Comment: post ur query too...

Comment: @AntonyJack: please see my update

Comment: what is your expected output... like array...

Comment: @AntonyJack: array good idea. ie: add `[selected] => selected` to array list

Comment: @H3llC0d3r kindly check my answer maybe it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with one query but for this, you need one extra column in query for checking category is using or not.

```
SELECT id,  name, if(pc.cat_id IS NULL,0,1) as `value` from categories as ct   LEFT JOIN post_categories as pc on pc.cat_id = ct.id
```

> [demo link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qsJKe5coRgw7KxrfsFU2CT/0)

I hope this query will fulfill your requirements.

If you need more detail about this you can visit this StackOverflow thread
[MySQL Join and create new column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14817225/mysql-join-and-create-new-column-value)

Answer (score 0):

You can run below query to get the categories selected:

```
select post_categories.category_id from posts 
left join post_categories on post_categories.post_id=posts.id
left join categories on post_categories.category_id=categories.id;
```

get these ids to an array and within your category loop check if the ids are in array and make them checked.

quite easy !

Comment: your code show only categories for posts like this output:`Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [category_id] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [category_id] => 2
        )

)` I need to: first list all categories then select categories for posts.

Comment: First you need to run above query to have an array with the necessary category ids. Then run select * from categories; and loop the output in a foreach and within that loop use your previously created array to check if the category ids are present. if yes, make the input checkbox checked.

Comment: Sure your method is for two query so without join method(one query). if right, please update your answer for your idea